# Return a concatenated string in Haskell recursive function

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am trying to write a function in haskell that would take an integer and return a concatenated (number of times the input) string

For Instance,

Input: 3

Output: hi1\nhi2\nhi3

```
main = do 

    let str = func 2 ""
    putStrLn str

func :: Int -> String -> String
func i str = do
        if i>(-1)
            then do
                str ++ "hi" ++ (show i)
                func (i-1) str

        else str
```

Thanking you!

Comment: `func i str = unlines $ map (\j -> str ++ "hi" ++ show j) [1..i]`

Comment: thank you Alec, works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to make your code "work" (I'll explain the double quotes later) is to call `func` with the concatenated string as a parameter directly, without intermediate steps:

```
func :: Int -> String -> String
func i str = do
        if i > (-1)
            then func (i-1) (str ++ "hi" ++ (show i) ++ "\n")       
            else str
```

I also added the newline character to the output, which means that the last character of the result will be a new line. Therefore it is better to write

```
let str = func 2 ""
putStr str
```

That way you'll avoid an extra new line at the end.

I wrote "works" in double quotes in the first sentence, because my code prints

```
hi2
hi1
hi0
```

You need to modify `func` so that the lines are printed in reverse order. Hint: you can store the lines in a list and reverse the list at the end.

P.S. I'm not sure whether zero should be a valid suffix. If not, then you have to change the condition in your `if` statement.

Comment: There is no need for any `do` notation in the implementation of `func`.

Comment: Thank you kapol :)

Comment: using `if-else` here is pretty bad style

Answer (score 3):

This is a much more idiomatic solution than using `if-else`

> a function that would take an integer and return a concatenated (number of times the input) string

```
func :: Int -> String -> String
func 0 s = ""
func n s = s ++ func (n - 1) s

main = putStrLn (func 3 "hi")
```

Output

```
hihihi
```

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if 'logarithmic' solution is faster:

```
main = putStrLn $mul 7 "Hi"

mul :: Int -> String -> String
mul 0 _ = ""
mul 1 s = s
mul _ "" = ""
mul n s = let
            (q, r) = n `quotRem` 2
            s' = mul q s
    in (if r == 1 then s else "") ++ s' ++ s'
```

Comment: This performs fewer recursive calls, but the cost of `s' ++ s'` is O(n), which should negate the advantage. I would expect this to use a double amount of memory, if not worse. In the general case, calling `++` with a large left list argument is not a good idea, since that list must be duplicated to produce the result.

Comment: There is a much better way to concatenate lists: pack them into functions, combine them with the `.` operator, and apply `[]` when done. You can use `id` to represent empty strings and pack the string `s` into a function like this: `(s ++)`. It helps because it makes sure only one call to `++` is on the call stack at any given time.